# How to use One image parts as backgrounds for different elements

Tags: html, css

[One Pic](https://www-udemy-com.global.ssl.fastly.net/static/images/v3/sprites.png?v=17)

How can the website use one image and use its parts as backgrounds for different elements , How can this be achieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They simply use different background positions to specify which image on the sprite sheet/picture they are using. For example inspect the element of the ufo image you have highlighted above. And change the `css background position to -390px` then the above and below images will become the same as positive specified will be same.

This is done to reduce the load on the server since now only one Image is loaded - the main picture instead of 10 different ones.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UgYYw/6/) here i have used [this image](http://rue89.nouvelobs.com/files/yanng/guerreduweb/css/img/bataille-item-home-main.jpg) and just using different background position for each img's css code. Please ask if you need further clarification.

Comment: can you give a example please so i can understand it

Comment: Sure hold on a second i'll do that @Waqas

Comment: and tell me how the other tags know that this is the image that is for background

Comment: I updated my answer with a jsFiddle. Please select the tick next to the answer if this solves your query! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set this background for any span you want. Rest to do is to cut the right part out.

Let's say you have one class for the image, it's:

```
.sp {
    background-image: url(your/picture.png);
}
```

You apply this class to all spans that need the picture.
Then you cut out single pics from it:

```
.sp.button1 {
    background-position: 20px 50px;
    height: 28px;
    width: 50px
}
```

(random nubmers)

You can specifiy you first pic with `class="sp button1"` then.

Comment: The dot is used in CSS to define a class. When your adding this class in HTML, you skip it - yes.